# What makes a heap-based Scheme slower than a stack-based Scheme?

Tags: compiler-construction, scheme, compiler-optimization

I am developing a compiler for a language similar to Scheme, and am reading through Dybvig's thesis. In it, he says that achieved most of his performance gain by allocating call frames on the stack instead of on the heap. There's several tricks that need to be done in order to actually make this work in the presence of closures and continuations.

My question is where does this performance gain come from? Is it purely because we put less strain on the garbage collector?

Put another way: Assuming we have an infinite amount of memory, would stack allocated call frames still be faster than heap allocated call frames?

Comment: You mention "the garbage collector" - what's your implementation language?

Comment: My implementation language is C. But I should clarify, I meant performance gain for the compiled code, *not* performance gain for the compiler itself.

Comment: Note really an answer but: (a) dealing with the heap takes more time since it requires scanning it (it's not linear like the stack); (b) practically all cpu architectures put extra emphasis on making stack access as fast as possible, and no so with the heap.

Comment: I don't know very much about architecture, so (b) is interesting to me.

As to (a), I am using a stop-and-copy garbage collector so allocation on the heap is as cheap as it is on the stack. 

The reason I ask is, there seems to be a lot of overhead involved with Dybvig's solution, and the only advantage I can see so far (aside from CPU support) is less callframes to clean up afterwards.

Answer (score 4):

I think Eli answered your question, so I'm going to paste his comment here and get credit for it :).

Eli Barzilay writes:

(a) dealing with the heap takes more time since it requires scanning it (it's not linear like the stack); (b) practically all cpu architectures put extra emphasis on making stack access as fast as possible, and not so with the heap.

To this I would add general hand-waving about cache locality. That is, a stack keeps all the action in a very small part of memory, which will almost definitely stay in the cache.

Comment: I would also add that garbage collection on the stack is very cheap (popping frames) in comparison to collecting a heap.

Answer (score 0):

Appel wrote a [paper](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~appel/papers/45.ps) claiming that heap allocation can be faster than stack allocation. Mathematically he is correct, but he ignores how modern processors are tailored to running code that uses a stack (cache locality, efficient stack instructions etc.) and that heap accesses have more indirections (bad in modern CPUs).